# How to list all vpc's and security groups?

Tags: ruby, aws-sdk

I want to be able to describe my network, starting from [Virtual Private Clouds](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/) (VPCs)?

1. How can I list all VPC's that I currently have?
2. Given a VPC, can I describe all the resources in the VPC like security groups?

Answer (score 1):

To describe VPCs, use [DescribeVpcs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2016-11-15.html#describevpcs):

```
$result = $client->describeVpcs([
    'DryRun' => true || false,
    'Filters' => [
        [
            'Name' => '<string>',
            'Values' => ['<string>', ...],
        ],
        // ...
    ],
    'VpcIds' => ['<string>', ...],
]);
```

To list Security Groups, use [DescribeSecurityGroups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2016-11-15.html#describesecuritygroups):

```
$result = $client->describeSecurityGroups([
    'DryRun' => true || false,
    'Filters' => [
        [
            'Name' => '<string>',
            'Values' => ['<string>', ...],
        ],
        // ...
    ],
    'GroupIds' => ['<string>', ...],
    'GroupNames' => ['<string>', ...],
]);
```

Alternatively, you may wish to [configure AWS Config to provide a daily configuration snapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/deliver-snapshot-cli.html) into an Amazon S3 bucket that contains all this information.

Comment: I wanted to restrict this to a particular VPC.  BTW, where is the API doc where I can search for these methods?

Comment: My answer includes links to the documentation, eg [DescribeVpcs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2016-11-15.html#describevpcs)