# how to list all VPCs in my aws account using ruby sdk 3

Tags: ruby, aws-sdk, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to list all of the VPCs associated with my AWS account using the ruby sdk, but I can't seem to find the correct methods to do it.  Can someone please point me to the correct method to call?

Comment: Please edit to show all relevant work, including what you've tried, inputs, expected vs actual outputs, errors, etc. As written, this only contains a requirement with nothing else.

Comment: @DavidMakogon thanks for the feedback.  I'm have not tried anything because in my statement, I've stated that I don't know which method in the sdk to call to list all the VPCs in my account.

Comment: Right, so... the issue is, that type of question is off-topic for Stack Overflow (it starts edging into "tutorial" or "documentation request," which is explicitly off-topic here)

Comment: this is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41864986/how-to-list-all-vpcs-and-security-groups (which was posted over 5 years ago).  Perhaps someone will entertain my question.

Comment: That question is off-topic, as written, fyi. If you disagree with something about Stack Overflow, such as how questions might be deemed on- or off-topic, you can post a question on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) (questions specific to the site itself).

Comment: @DavidMakogon, FYI, I figured out the solution and posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and would like to post the solution so others can use it as a reference.  In short, the ruby SDK method [describe_vpcs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/EC2/Client.html#describe_vpcs-instance_method) does the trick.  Please note that we have to make that call for each region to tally up all VPCs in the account.